# Get shortest distance between two points

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to calculate **shortest** distance between two points. I am using below function to achieve that.

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(6.71532762,80.06215197);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(6.93234287,79.84870747);

var distance = document.getElementById('distance');
distance.innerHTML = distance.innerHTML+calcDistance(p1, p2);

//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);  
}
```

This gives **33.77 km** as distance. But according to [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/6.71532762,80.06215197/6.93234287,79.84870747), **shortest** distance between above points should be **45.0 km**.

How could I get that value? (**45.0 km**)

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uc6t7br5/).

Comment: Note that the method you're calling is "google.maps.geometry. **spherical** .computeDistanceBetween" which I suspect is the great circle distance between the two points (i.e. shortest distance around the globe).

Comment: I measured the distance in Google Maps myself and got **~33.7 km** as a result. Edit: I suppose you got the **45 km** from the distance on road. This is not the function you are looking for if you want to measure distance by road. [See this link for that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/direction)

Comment: Computing spherical distance != distance traveled via roads. Please specify what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the road distance, you can use google.maps.DirectionsService() :

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(6.71532762, 80.06215197);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(6.93234287, 79.84870747);

function getShortestDistance(p1, p2) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = {
      origin: p1,
      destination: p2,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      provideRouteAlternatives: true
    };
    new google.maps.DirectionsService().route(request, function(response, status) {
      var minRoute = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
        if (minRoute === null || response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value < minRoute.legs[0].distance.value) {
          minRoute = response.routes[i];
        }
      }
      resolve(minRoute);
    });
  });
}

getShortestDistance(p1, p2).then(function(result) {
  document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = 'Distance : ' +     result.legs[0].distance.text;
});
```

You can find the library here : https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this gives **Fastest route**. But what I need is **Shortest route**

Comment: Then I think you can add provideRouteAlternatives: true in the request to get alternative routes and select the shortest.

Comment: Yeah, Just found that. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to find the shortest route. I am getting 45km, which is what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The spherical distance is the distance in a straight line from a - b  (as the bird flies)

The google maps link you posted shows a street that is 45km long.

EDIT: To get the shortest street distance you need to have a look into the google maps directions API instead of the spherical method:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yeah, I need to get the distance of that street that is 45 km long.

Comment: Then you should have a look into the google maps directions API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. I'll check this.